# The largest value of $k$ for $\Bbb{Z}^{k}$ to be embedded in $\mathcal{GL}(n,\Bbb{Z})$.

Tags: group-theory

Reading my course on  group theory, I asked my self the following question :

> Suppose that $\Bbb{Z}^{k}$ can be embedded in $\mathcal{GL}(n,\Bbb{Z})$. What is the largest value of $k$?

Comment: In other words, you are asking about the maximum rank of a free abelian subgroup of $\mathcal{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$. By the way, why did you include the [finite-groups] tag?

Comment: I think the answer is about $\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor^2$ (the exact number depends on the parity of $n$), which you get as a group of upper unitriangular matrices with off-diagonal entries all within a square at the top right, but I am not going to try and prove it.

Comment: @DerekHolt I will try by myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Derek was almost right: The precise answer is that the largest rank (call it $r$) of a free abelian subgroup of $SL(n,Z)$  equals 
$$
d=\left[\frac{n^2}{4} \right] 
$$
where the bracket is the floor function. The proof is a bit heavy. To see that $r\ge d$ you construct a free abelian subgroup $H$ of rank $d$ as the subgroup of matrices of the form 
$$
I + (a_{ij})
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $a_{ij}\in Z$ is zero provided $i(j+1)=0$ modulo $2$. This means that the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ has the form
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & * & 0 & * ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
0 & * & 0 & * ...\\
& & \ldots  & &
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Hence, each matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ has exactly $d$ entries which are, potentially, nonzero. I leave you to check that $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $SL(n,Z)$ and is isomorphic to $Z^d$. 
(The key is that $(I+A)(I+A')= I+ A + A'$ for all matrices $A, A'$ of the above type.)

To get the upper bound, you have to use some heavy machinery (or not so heavy if you saw this staff before): If $H$ is a free abelian subgroup of $SL(n,Z)$ of rank $k$, you take the *Zariski closure* $\bar{H}$ of $H$ in $SL(n,R)$; the result is isomorphic to the additive group $R^k$. Then you take the Lie algebra of $\bar{H}$; it is a rank $k$ commutative subalgebra $a$ of the Lie algebra $g$ of traceless $n\times n$ real matrices. Then you do a bit of googling and discover [this conversation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29087/commutative-subalgebras-of-m-n), from which you learn that the maximal dimension of $a\subset g$ is exactly $d$ (it seems that the result was first proven by I.Schur). Therefore, $r\le d$.

Combining this, you obtain that $r=d$. Lastly, since the group $SL(n,Z)$ has finite index in $GL(n,Z)$, the ranks of their maximal free abelian subgroups are the same.

Comment: Surely an excellent answer, I am unfamiliar with lie algebra and Zariski closure but I will read on it to anderstand your answer. Thanks a lot. +1

Comment: @studiosus  Wow. This is really nice.