# The maximal free abelian subgroup that can be embedded in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group, maximal-subgroup

I am stuck on this problem and cannot seem to find a good reason for drawing the required conclusion. The problem is as follows:

> Given $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ a subroup in $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. How can one prove that the ranks of their maximal free abelian subgroups are the same?

Roughly speaking, This is what I have done. Take $F$ to be the maximal free abelian subgroup of $Sl(n,\mathbb{Z})$. It is a free abelian subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose we have an element $x$ in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ that commutes with $F$.  now I need to show that $x$ is in $F$ or in just in $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ to conclude a contradiction with the fact that $F$ is maximal free abelian in $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. Maybe I should use the fact that $Sl(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has index $2$ in $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe you could use that if $F'$ is a free abelian subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$, then $(F')^2 \subseteq SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is a free abelian subgroup of the same rank as $F'$?  (Haven't checked the details...)

Comment: Your question is poorly stated. I suspect that what you have meant to ask is if maxima of ranks of abelian subgroups of $SL(n , Z)$ and of $GL(n,Z)$ are the same. This is of course true since the groups are commensurable.

Comment: @DanielSchepler How did you prove that $(F')^2$ is in $SL(n,Z)$. now suppode that (F')^2 is in $SL(n,Z)$ and has the same rank as $F'$ so how can i conclude that $F'$ has the same rank as $F$ ??

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes this is what I meant ... how did you use the fact that those groups are commensurable to conclude that $F'$ and $F$ have the same rank ???

Comment: Prove that if $_1<_2$  are abelian groups and $|_2:_1|<∞$ 
 then $_1\otimes {\mathbb Q}=_2\otimes {\mathbb Q}$ 
 (without the finite index assumption you have a natural inclusion $_1\otimes {\mathbb Q}\subset_2\otimes {\mathbb Q}$).

Comment: Incidentally, the maximal rank will be equal $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858879/the-largest-value-of-k-for-bbbzk-to-be-embedded-in-mathcalgln-bb/863066#863066).

Comment: @MoisheKohan if you look at the conversation that you have mentioned you will find at the end of it that he stated the same thing that I am trying to prove ... he directly says that " since $SL(n,Z)$ has a finite index in $GL(n,Z)$ then the rank of their maximal free abelian groups are the same" without any details maybe it seems obvious to him but for me it is difficult

Answer (score 2):

Your own final sentence is a good hint. I'll improve the hint with two questions.

Take $F$ to be a maximal free abelian subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$.

- Knowing that $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ has index 2 in $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$, what can you say about the index of $F' = F \cap SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ in $F$?
- Given a free abelian group $F$ of a certain rank, and given a finite index subgroup $F'$ of $F$, what can you say about the rank of $F'$ in relation to the rank of $F$?

Comment: thanks, but I couldn't understand the meaning behind your answer, Concerning the second part we can say that rank(F') < rank(F) ...

Comment: You should perhaps look at explicit examples. What are examples of finite index subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, and what are their ranks? What are examples of finite index subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$, and what are their ranks?